# Picking out index of an array that satisfies certain restrictions

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array defined below

```
y = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,199,199,199]
```

I would like to iterate through and pick out the index of the elements that are either greater than 7, or less than 1. 
I was initially using the

```
np.where((y<0) & (y>7))
```

But that doesn't make sense at all. I haven't been able to figure out how to change the 'and' operator into a 'or'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[i for i, e in enumerate(y) if e > 7 or e < 1]
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to enumerate. Thanks.